# Replace space in a String with replaceAll not working in JAVA

Tags: java

I try to remove a space into a string which contains a int type value.

- I read a .csv file with the scanner methode.
- I use a Class to set/get the data.
- I format data into the setter of the class.

Input data example:

```
String Pu_ht = "1 635,90";
```

Basic Example:

```
/**
 * @param Pu_ht the Pu_ht to set
 */
public void setPu_ht(String Pu_ht) {
    this.Pu_ht = Pu_ht.replace(",", ".").replace(".00", "");
}
```

Tried example:

```
  /**
 * @param Pu_ht the Pu_ht to set
 */
public void setPu_ht(String Pu_ht) {
    this.Pu_ht = Pu_ht.replace(",", ".").replace(".00", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "");
}
```

Other example:

```
 /**
 * @param Pu_ht the Pu_ht to set
 */
public void setPu_ht(String Pu_ht) {
    this.Pu_ht = Pu_ht.replace(",", ".").replace(".00", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

Output data example: 1 635.90

I tried a lots of things but nothing work for my case.

Best regards

EDIT:

My code:

```
 public void requete_pommes() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // open file input stream
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    // read file line by line
    String line = null;
    Scanner scanner = null;
    int index = 0;
    List<Pommes> pomList = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean firstLine = false;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!(line.equals(";;;;TOTAL HT"))) {

            if (!(line.equals(";;;;"))) {

                Pommes pom = new Pommes();
                scanner = new Scanner(line);
                scanner.useDelimiter(";");
                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    String data = scanner.next();


                    pom.setNumero_compte("21826");
                    if ((index == 0)) {
                        pom.setReference(data);
                    } else if ((index == 1)) {
                        pom.setDesignation(data);
                    } else if ((index == 2)) {
                        pom.setQte(data);
                    } else if ((index == 3)) {
                         if(data.equals("1 635,90")){
                              data = data.replaceAll("\\s","");
                              System.err.println("data: " + data);
                         }
                        pom.setPu_ht(data);
                    } else if ((index == 4)) {
                        pom.setMontant_HT(data);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("invalid data::" + data);
                    }
                    pom.setNumero_commande("1554");

                    index++;
                }
                index = 0;
                pomList.add(pom);

                requeteCorps = "(( SELECT codea FROM article WHERE tarif7 != 'O' AND tarif8 = 'O' AND pvente > 0 AND  COALESCE(trim( reffou), '') != '' AND reffou = '" + pom.getReference() + "' ), " + pom.getQte() + " , " + pom.getPu_ht() + ", '" + kapiece + "', 'stomag','vendu', getnum('LCK')),";

                ar.add(requeteCorps);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: please provide an [mcve]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: *I format data into the setter of the class* that is not a good idea. Formatting should be done by the view not by a setter

Comment: You are putting up a lot of things, but we would only need: input example, expected output, and what you actually got. Besides: read about java naming conventions. For example you only use _ in SOME_CONSTANT. And please note: the javadoc you have there is really pointless. That is nothing but line noise - and of course: it is lying! Your method is not only setting a value, but also **formatting** whatever comes in. Rather call it `formatAndSet()` or something alike.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Both of your attempts work on my computer and yield 1635.90 (without any space).

Comment: please share your full implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value "1 635,90" probably stems from a locale specific format, and the "space" actually is a non-breaking space, `\u00A0`. This is done often to prevent in flexible width text representation a line break to happen inside a number.

```
s = s.replace("\u00A0", "");
```

Comment: Work like a charm ! Thank you !

Comment: Funny that a no-break space doesn’t count as whitespace with regex `\s`. I can confirm that it doesn’t, so it is necessary to mention it explicitly as in the code in the answer.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, quaint. Explainable as a nbsp glues two text pieces into one: in physics: an antispace.

Answer (score 0):

```
String Pu_ht = "1 635,90";
System.out.println(Pu_ht.replace(",", ".").replace(".00", "").replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
```

just put the above codes in main method and execute. the output will be `1635.90`,then examine your codes.